# Silverlight Scrolling Tab Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabs, scroll, controls

I am wanting to create a sivlerlight tab control where the tabs remain on a single line and scroll buttons will allow me to scroll left or right through the tabs.  Below is a link to a control that can be purchased but I would like to write my own and share it with the community.  I know I can create a inherited class and style with buttons for the tab control. I guess I am confused on how to keep the tabs on one line and scroll the tabs so only half of a tab would be shown.  Can you all help with this?  If I way off base please correct my direction.

[Sample tab control](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TabControl/FirstLook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I have created the TabControl in which the tabs are situated on the single line.
[image]

I have written [the blog post](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/silverlight-tabcontrol-with-scrolling-and-with-the-new-tab-button/) where I've explained some details.

Also you can download the project directly [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/WordPress/ExtendedTabControl.zip).

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct would be to create a control that has a `ScrollViewer` with a `WrapPanel`  inside it (from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases)) that is flowing horizontally. Then you can add the tab buttons to the flow panel and you should have the scroll behaviour.

Of course, if you don't want a scroll bar but instead want buttons, you can do the same thing but hide the scroll bars, then embed the whole thing in a `Grid` with three columns. Have the `ScrollViewer` sit in column 0 with a `columnspan` of 3 and then add a button to columns 0 and 2  that you can show and hide when the mouse rolls over that cell of the grid. You could then somehow scroll the viewer when the buttons are pressed.